# PC activity monitor for my network

Tags: networking, display

Are there any free software for  monitoring PC  activity? I own a comp with five system and i want to monitor employee activities with their computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with freebies, the selection is rather limited ... if you're looking for something more sophisticated such as sending email alerts, screen capture, etc, you'll have to consider a a commercial solution.

**[Free KGB Key Logger](http://download.cnet.com/Free-KGB-Key-Logger/3000-2162_4-10357898.html)**

True to its name, the application captures all typed keystrokes, but it also can log visited Web sites and record Clipboard contents.

**[KidLogger](http://www.rohos.com/kid-logger/)** can log all websites visited, chat rooms talks, started programs, opened documents and windows viewed pictures and movies. It is also a simple and FREE key logger and activity monitoring program.

Comment: Note that depending on your business's location, you may want to be careful legally, as you can get into hot water if you end up capturing things like an employee's bank website password, etc, esp. without their knowledge.